# Declare surfaceGestureDetector object, distort the entire image

Tags: android, andengine

My code below using `ANDEngine` suppose to works fine on `SimpleBaseGameActivity`, where the 2 `Sprite` will animate and move. However when because it declare a `surfaceGestureDetector` object, the image get distorted. I didn't even use that object. By commenting out

```
gDetector = new SurfaceGestureDetector(this){...}
```

everything turns normal. Can someone advice what goes wrong? Thanks!

```
public class MainActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity
{

    private Camera camera;
    private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;

    private BitmapTextureAtlas yourTexture;
    private TiledTextureRegion yourTextureRegion;
    private SurfaceGestureDetector gDetector;


    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions()
    {
        camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, 
            new FillResolutionPolicy(), camera);
        engineOptions.getTouchOptions().setNeedsMultiTouch(true);

        return engineOptions;
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreateResources()
    {
        loadGraphics();

    }

    private void loadGraphics()
    {
        BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
        yourTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(getTextureManager(), 50, 200, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
        yourTextureRegion =BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(yourTexture, this, "snowman_animate.png", 0, 0, 1, 4); 
        yourTexture.load();    
    }


    @Override
    public Scene onCreateScene() {
    Scene scene = new Scene();
    scene.setBackground(new Background(0.6004f, 0.6274f, 0.8784f));

    gDetector = new SurfaceGestureDetector(this){
            @Override
            protected boolean onSwipeUp() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean onSwipeRight() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean onSwipeLeft() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean onSwipeDown() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean onSingleTap() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            protected boolean onDoubleTap() {
                return false;
            }
        };


        MySprite yourSprite = new MySprite(200, 400, yourTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        MySprite yourSprite2 = new MySprite(300, 200, yourTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        long[] frameDurration = {250, 250, 250, 250};
        yourSprite.animate(frameDurration);
        yourSprite2.animate(frameDurration);

        scene.attachChild(yourSprite);
        scene.attachChild(yourSprite2);

        return scene;

    }

    private static class MySprite extends AnimatedSprite {
        private final PhysicsHandler mPhysicsHandler;

        public MySprite
            (final float pX, final float pY, final TiledTextureRegion pTextureRegion, final VertexBufferObjectManager pVertexBufferObjectManager) {
            super(pX, pY, pTextureRegion, pVertexBufferObjectManager);
            this.mPhysicsHandler = new PhysicsHandler(this);
            this.registerUpdateHandler(this.mPhysicsHandler);
            this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocity(0, 120);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onManagedUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {

            if(this.mY < 0) {
                this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityY(120);
            } else if(this.mY + this.getHeight() > CAMERA_HEIGHT) {
                this.mPhysicsHandler.setVelocityY(-120);
            }

            super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to my problem. Though I don't understand why. I would need to declare it in onCreate instead of in onCreateScene, as below.

```
public void onCreate(final Bundle pSavedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(pSavedInstanceState);
    gDetector = new SurfaceGestureDetector(this){
        @Override
        protected boolean onSwipeUp() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean onSwipeRight() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean onSwipeLeft() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean onSwipeDown() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean onSingleTap() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean onDoubleTap() {
            return false;
        }
    };

}
```